# Erlang: Building Issue of not finding Ncurses on Solaris 10

Tags: erlang, ncurses, solaris-10

I am trying to build Erlang on Solaris 10. The build process fails with the message that it can not find libncurses.so.5.
I have installed libncurses from sunfreeware.com, which I have build from scratch and has installed itself in /usr/local/lib/.
I have tried to set LDFLAGS with -L/usr/local/lib/ but have still had no luck.
What am I missing so that make picks up the library?
 
I am using GNU Make 3.81 and GCC 3.4.6.

Comment: On solaris, is it not possible to run ./configure and have it detect libncurses for you?

Comment: I realized that I did not call configure again after installing libncurses - but it did not help.

Comment: Try removing the directory and untar the sources again to start out fresh. (I forget if it is enough to remove ./.config.cache or something like that.) The missing ncurses might have been cached and is now a "fact" to autoconf.

Comment: ok - I tried again with DED_LD=ldd and LD_LIBARY_PATH with /usr/lib and it went over this, but I still saw a couple strange errors at different places - if it does not work soon I will take the old OpenCSW file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the relevant bit from config.log?

Did you also set the include path with -I in either CPPFLAGS or CFLAGS?

**Update:** You could also try installing Erlang from [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/erlang) instead.

Comment: grep curses */*.log<br>
erts/config.log:configure:8643: checking for tgetent in -lncurses<br>
erts/config.log:configure:8673: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/scripts/temp/otp_src_R13B02-1/erts/sparc-sun-solaris2.10  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    conftest.c -lncurses  -ldl -lm   >&5 <br>
erts/config.log:ac_cv_lib_ncurses___tgetent=yes
erts/config.log:TERMCAP_LIB='-lncurses'<br>